# Python Django Error on local in windows

Tags: python

i found an error while running webservice on local

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\wamp\www\mysite_livebackupcode\django-apps\mysite\account\views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.middleware.csrf import CsrfViewMiddleware, get_token
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\middleware\csrf.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\cache.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import get_cache
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\cache\__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either
define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

can anybody please help me to get out of this stuff.

thanks in advance

Comment: How are you running this? You should be using `manage.py runserver` to get the local test-server.

Comment: Have your changed the path of settings.py?

Comment: yes i have set in settings.py

Comment: @DanielB it return "AccessInit: hash collision: 3 for both 1 and 1", is it seems working or error..?

Comment: @KrunalShah are you using PIL? http://jaredforsyth.com/blog/2010/apr/28/accessinit-hash-collision-3-both-1-and-1/

Answer (score 2):

You can set environment variable in linux for example:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings
```

It should help you.

Comment: So you can also set it :) by cmd or right click on my computer and somewhere there is enviroment settings

Comment: Could you show us your settings file? Do you have section about CACHE?

Comment: sorry i cant share, and i have checked, there is no section regarding cache

Comment: Hmm may u shall add default value for cache? 
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    }
}

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/